# Fortran Input Files from Mac OS to XP

Tags: fortran90

I recently got some Fortran code, which successfully ran on Mac OS. This code along with input files were later sent to me to get compiled. I precisely used the same code and the same input files but an error "array bounds exceeded" appeared. I am using CVF 6.6 on Windows XP. 
I wanted to know the following things:

1. Is this a compiler or OS problem?
2. Shall I arrange a Mac OS to get them compiled?
3. After surfing so much on internet I think the wise thing to do is to get my data "format free". But I don't how to do that when my data is a time series with time in one column and voltage in the second.

Answer (score 1):

The error message `array bounds exceeded` always (I think) indicates that your code has tried to access an array element outside the bounds of an array, for example element 25 in an array with 24 elements.  This can only occur at run-time, and your compiler/run-time will only spot it if, when compiling, you set on the compiler option(s) for *array bounds checking*; your compiler documentation will tell you what those options are.

The error message should have been accompanied by some more information telling you where in the program the error occurred and the index of the out-of-bounds array access.

Given that your source code and your input data are identical how could this have occurred ?  Since you have compiled the program on 2 different platforms your compilations cannot have been identical, it is entirely possible that array bounds checking is switched off on your Mac and on on your Windows PC.

Fortran programs may execute apparently successfully despite making accesses to out-of-bounds array elements.  If the memory address of array element 25 out of 24 holds a value which is meaningful and the address is within your program's space the computation is likely to continue.  It is also likely to be useless, but you can go for many years before finding that out.

I suggest that you go back to the Mac, recompile with array bounds checking, and run again, see what happens.

It's also possible that the routines which read your file find a different number of values on XP and Mac; I suspect that can be caused by different line ending characters, even by whether or not the input file has a newline at the end. Check this too.

Comment: Thankyou very much for you prompt reply. just for my own knowledge, can i turn off array bound checking in my windows? how can i do that, if its possible???

Comment: I'm not going to give you any assistance in doing something as dangerous as switching off an essential safety mechanism, what you ask is akin to asking how to open an aircraft door while it is in flight.  First, get your program working properly on the Mac, then on Windows.  Then, and only then (and then only because run time array bounds checking has performance implications) you can switch the checks off.